# Understand PowerShell version

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a VPS with PowerShell installed. How do I know if it's a RTM or CTP?

I ran $host.Version and I got :

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

WTF are the minus-one's? I've never seen negative numbers for any of a version fragments..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the more conventional way of getting the version number is using the [$PSVersionTable](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/2617.aspx)  which gives a build version value.  Although `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` gives me what you get.. Hmm -ve builds!!

If it makes you feel any better, I'm running PS Version 2 RTM  on Windows 7 and i get the same result as you.  My  $PSVersionTable.BuildVersion is 6.1.7600.16385  which is the same version number i get when i look at the product version on the powershell.exe  with:

```
(gcm "$PSHome\PowerShell.exe").FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

Comment: So... having version 2.0.-1.-1 means I have the RTM? The reason for all the fuss is that some software (SharePoint 2010 beta for example) requires PowerShell 2.0 RTM

Comment: that build version looks to be v2 RTM.  The  Windows 7 ( & win2k8 R2) version seems to have a newer build of ps v2

Comment: -1 & -1 seem to mean nothing at all!

Answer (score 2):

You can get a little more detailed information like this:

```
PS > $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.4200
BuildVersion                   6.0.6002.18139
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

And

```
PS > $Host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : [obscured]
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserI
                   nterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

I would interpret the "-1" values as "not applicable".